# How can I display 3D graphs in an Angular application?

Tags: angular, highcharts, plotly

I'm trying to display a customizable 3D Scatterplot in an Angular application. So far I've tried highcharts.js and Plotly but none of the solutions worked. Highcharts should support Angular but there is no documentation for it anywhere. If anybody has a working example with highcharts or another solution it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Highcharts Angular wrapper you can use.

**More information:**
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-angular-wrapper/

Please find attached a 3d scatter chart demo you can base on.

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-scatter-3d-rncytq?file=src/app/app.component.ts